# Using conditionals in tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, tikz-node

**EDIT** Through carelessness, I misrepresented the error that I was getting. I have corrected the example code and my comments.

I'd like to be able to setup 1 Ti*k*Z node `.style` altered by conditionals. The advantage is having one `.style` instead of many. Simple conditionals work, but anything requiring `\ifsometest something=something else \fi` fails.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifdash
\newif\ifdouble

\def\doublecolor{yellow}
\def\mydots{dash dot dot}

\tikzset{%
    boxes/.style={%
        thick,
        draw,
        % This works:
        \ifdash \mydots\fi,
        % This works:
        % double=\doublecolor,
        % But this causes error: Use of \pgfkeys@sp@b doesn't match its definition.
        \ifdouble double=\doublecolor \fi,
        % As does this: 
        % \ifdouble double/.expand once=\doublecolor\fi,
    }%
}

\begin{document}

    \tikz\node[boxes] {\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}};

    \dashtrue

    \tikz\node[boxes] {\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}};

\end{document}
```

This fails with this error message:

```
./if-in-node-options.tex:30: Use of \pgfkeys@sp@b doesn't match its definition.

\pgfkeys@spdef ...e \pgfkeys@sp@a #2\pgfkeys@stop 
                                              \pgfkeys@stop        \pgfkeys@st...
l.30    \tikz\node[boxes]
                    {\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}};
```

The question is this: Is there any way to do something like:

```
\ifdouble double=\doublecolor\fi
```

or not? Again, while multiple styles are possible based on the requirements -- which I've already done -- I'm looking for something simpler if possible.

Comment: The `r` is missing from `\doublecolor` in your MWE, is that on purpose?

Comment: No ;( , not on purpose -- an annoying finger-fluff. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend the following:

```
\tikzset{%
    boxes/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{
           thick,
           draw
        }
        \ifdouble
          \pgfkeysalso{double=\doublecolor}
        \fi
    }%
}
```

`some key/.style={some other keys,...}` is shorthand for `some key/.code={\pgfkeysalso{some other keys,...}}`. If you need any logic in your style code, one solution is to fall back to using the `/.code` handler and `\pgfkeysalso` around the actual keys.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifdash
\newif\ifdouble

\def\doublecolor{yellow}
\def\mydots{dash dot dot}

\tikzset{%
    boxes/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{
           thick,
           draw
        }
        \ifdouble
          \pgfkeysalso{double=\doublecolor}
        \fi
    }%
}

\begin{document}

    \tikz\node[boxes] {\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}};

    \dashtrue

    \tikz\node[boxes] {\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}};

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Two problems with the approach of the question:

- The syntax characters `=` and `,` should not be inside an `\if` construct.
- The option settings in `\tikzset` is executed immediately. Setting the `\if` switches later has no effect.

The following example uses styles to add additional properties to style `boxes`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\doublecolor{yellow}
\def\mydots{dash dot dot}

\tikzset{%
  boxes/.style={%
    thick,
    draw,
  },
  set dash/.style={%
    boxes/.append style={\mydots},%
  },%
  set double/.style={%
    boxes/.append style={double=\doublecolor},%
  },%
}

\begin{document}

    \tikz\node[boxes] {\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[2]\end{minipage}};

    \medskip
    \tikz[set dash, set double]
      \node[boxes] {\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[2]\end{minipage}};

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]